# AS3 Serialization

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, serialization, file-io, flash-builder

*What I'm trying to do:*

-Have objects in a toolbar, drag and dropable onto a movieclip (they then become a child of the movieclip). Once this is done, I want to be able serialize this object, so I can save it to a file. Then, I can reload this file, and continue draging/dropping things onto/off of this movieclip.

*How I'm doing it:*

```
public class Serialization {
    public static function serializeToString(value:Object):String{
        if(value==null){
            trace("null isn't a legal serialization candidate");
        }
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytes.writeObject(value);
        bytes.position = 0;
        var be:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
        be.encode(bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length));
        return be.drain();
    }

    public static function readObjectFromStringBytes(value:String):Object{
        var dec:Base64Decoder=new Base64Decoder();
        dec.decode(value);
        var result:ByteArray=dec.drain();
        result.position=0;
        return result.readObject();
    }      
}
```

This is where call the function/write it to the file:

```
        var fr:FileReference = new FileReference;
        fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, success);
        var txtString:String = new String();
        txtString = save.Serialization.serializeToString(pagePic);
        trace(txtString);
        fr.save(txtString, "test.txt");
```

Unfortunately, txtString appears to be blank. Am I approaching this wrong?

Side notes:
This is being developed for a mobile platform.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  drain() isn't a documented method in the Base63Encoder class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html

Comment: I'm under the impression drain simply changes encoded bytes into a string.

Comment: why You dont use AMF serialization and serialize objects itself ? bytes.writeObject(value);

Comment: @nameistaken1 Based on your usage that makes sense; however it isn't a documented method on the class.  Are you sure you're using it properly?  Are you using a class different than the one I linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MovieClips, Sounds, and other resources cannot be serialized. My solution is to create a custom class that will store all my properties and reassign them upon loading, or just write to/parse a text file when saving/loading.